# Why is reading from a Rails cache for individual ActiveRecord fragments slower?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I am playing around with fragment caching and Russian doll caching and I noticed that when I implement caching for individual Activerecord objects and read from the cache, it's slower than if I didn't read from the cache at all. Rails log:

```
Read fragment views/28fd8a7abcc7ce35c0792325bd26883b (0.1ms)
  Cache digest for app/views/author/index.html.erb: 28fd8a7abcc7ce35c0792325bd26883b
Read fragment views/28fd8a7abcc7ce35c0792325bd26883b (0.0ms)
  Cache digest for app/views/author/index.html.erb: 28fd8a7abcc7ce35c0792325bd26883b
Read fragment views/28fd8a7abcc7ce35c0792325bd26883b (0.1ms)
  Cache digest for app/views/author/index.html.erb: 28fd8a7abcc7ce35c0792325bd26883b
Read fragment views/28fd8a7abcc7ce35c0792325bd26883b (0.1ms)
  Rendered author/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3799.8ms)
Completed 200 OK in 3828ms (Views: 3822.3ms | ActiveRecord: 4.8ms)
```

The view takes about 4 seconds to load on average.

This is my code:

```
<div class="author">
  <% @authors.each do |author| %>
    <% cache(p) do %>
      <h2>My name is <%= author.name %></h2>
      <% author.articles.each do |art| %>
        <p>I wrote: <span style="text-decoration: underline"><%= link_to art.name, articles_show_path(art) %> </span></p>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

But now if I remove the code, this is the time on average:

```
 Article Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."author_id" = ?  [["author_id", 1997]]
  Article Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."author_id" = ?  [["author_id", 1998]]
  Article Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."author_id" = ?  [["author_id", 1999]]
  Article Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."author_id" = ?  [["author_id", 2000]]
  Article Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "articles".* FROM "articles" WHERE "articles"."author_id" = ?  [["author_id", 2001]]
  Rendered author/index.html.erb within layouts/application (4422.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4464ms (Views: 3546.8ms | ActiveRecord: 915.2ms)
```

The view takes slightly less time to load on average. Is that right? Is it supposed to be that way?

If the view is slower to load, then why aren't we just fragment caching the whole section and why are we bothering with Russian doll caching. I realize that the benefit of Russian Doll caching is when objects are updated and outer fragments are automatically invalidated, nested fragments can be re-used. (russian dolls)... but if the nested fragments take longer to read then to just reload, why bother?

This is the Russian doll cache that I hope to implement:

```
<% cache(author_helper_method_cache) do %>
  <div class="author">
    <% @authors.each do |author| %>
      <% cache(p) do %>
        <h2>My name is <%= author.name %></h2>
        <% author.articles.each do |art| %>
          <p>I wrote: <span style="text-decoration: underline"><%= link_to art.name, articles_show_path(art) %> </span></p>
        <% end %>
      <% end %>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typical [N+1 query problem](http://www.sitepoint.com/silver-bullet-n1-problem/).

In your controller:

```
@authors = Author.where(your_conditions).includes(:atricles)
```

I think, cache is unnecessary for this case. Try without it, and test the performance.

Comment: This is more for demonstration and understanding. I know I have an n+1 problem.

Comment: So, do you want just to cache, without n+1 solving?

Comment: no I'm just trying to learn how to do both? I know how to do n+1 problem solving, but not the caching problem?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out why the cache solution is slower given a set of conditions.